# Using Eclipse/Aptana, points to wrong location when previewing in browser

Tags: eclipse, aptana

I'm just starting out with Eclipse Luna with Aptana plugin installed.

I've just written a basic .html file, and when I run the page using the built-in web server, it opens Firefox with the following URL:

http://127.0.0.1:8020/RemoteSystemsTempFiles/opening_page.html

This is unsuccesful, with Firefox displaying the message: Unable to connect

Whereas I have the file stored elsewhere on my hard drive. how do I point it in the right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found you can find the html file in your file explorer and open it manually or just type in the location the file is stored at on your hard drive into the address box. This worked for me with a html file and a css that changed the color. I am not sure if there is a setting somewhere to change the path it enters into Firefox.